# Method result in groupby

Tags: c#, linq

How can I group by method result?

```
var group = invoices.GroupBy(x => new { 
     x.User.IdUser, 
     x.PriceCatId, 
     x.Destination, 
     OrderHelper.ViewCyclesNames(x.Order.History.catId), 
     x.Cate 
}).ToList();
```

The compiler doesn't accept  `OrderHelper.ViewCyclesNames(x.Order.History.catId),` as a group by parameter.
How can I solve this?

Comment: What type does `OrderHelper.ViewCyclesNames(x.Order.History.catId)` return?

Comment: You need to provide a name: `GroupBy(x => new { ..., Names =  OrderHelper.ViewCyclesNames(x.Order.History.catId), ...})`. Compiler can deduce property names of your anonymous type if you use simple properties (`x.PriceCatId` is the same as `PriceCatId = x.PriceCatId`), but cannot do that for method calls.

Comment: Try : string.Join(",",OrderHelper.ViewCyclesNames(x.Order.History.catId)) which will make a CSV string.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko it returns string

Comment: Are you sure it returns a string and not List<string>?

Comment: It returns string with comma separators Example "ABC,CKD,KDL"

Comment: What happens if you do `invoices.ToList().GroupBy` linq to entity does not accept functions inside. It tries to interpret sql equivalent function

Comment: It might help if you list the error from the compiler, and the part of the code in error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your group-by expression creates an object of anonymous class:

```
new { 
     x.User.IdUser, 
     x.PriceCatId, 
    ...
}
```

C# compiler generates a class with properties corresponding to each expression inside curly braces. In order to do so the compiler must know the type of each object, and also the name it should give to the corresponding field. Hence, general syntax for a property of an anonymous class is as follows:

```
new { 
    PropertyName = SomeExpression
    ...
}
```

Note that generally you need a name followed by `=` to name the properties of your anonymous class. C# makes one exception from this rule: if `SomeExpression` is a property expression or a variable expression, the name of the property or variable from the expression is used to name the corresponding property of the anonymous type.

That is why four of the five properties from group-by expression do not cause any trouble. The property that gives you trouble is the only one that is *not* a property expression; hence, it requires an explicit name:

```
var group = invoices.GroupBy(x => new { 
     x.User.IdUser, 
     x.PriceCatId, 
     x.Destination, 
     ViewCyclesNames = OrderHelper.ViewCyclesNames(x.Order.History.catId), 
     x.Cate 
}).ToList();
```